# How to get the first day of the month in Azure data flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have "Date" column with yyyy-MM-dd format .I want to fetch the 1st day i.e,
if date is 2023-05-28 ----> 2023-05-01
I have tried method below
and apply it in

iif(toString(Date)>=substring(toString(currentDate()),1,8)+'01',substring(toString(Date),1,8)+'01',toString(null()))

Its working but not for all dates .I dont know wh.Is there any alternative ?

Comment: Can you give an example for which dates this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

- According to the condition written, you would get null values in every case where the date value belongs to the previous months. The required result would be generated only for dates that belong to current or future dates.
- Look at the following example. I have the following data in my date column.

[image]

- When I use the expression similar to yours, then it gives the result as shown in the below image:

[image]

- If you want to convert any date to get `yyyy-MM-01`, then you can directly use the dynamic content `substring(toString(date),1,8)+'01'`.

[image]